# List & Remove an EventBridge Lambda trigger using the CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I need to fetch information from a lambda function and remove an existing trigger (EventBridge) from this lambda using CLI (script needs to do that).

Tried to use `list-event-source-mappings` or `delete-event-source-mappings` but without success.

Seems like EventBridge isn't supported yet (showing me only SQS,Kinesis,DynamoDB,MQ,MSK) but maybe I am wrong and there is a solution?

---

###### Edit:

I have a working lambda function that has associated trigger with an Eventbridge rule which was already deleted in the past. It no longer exists in my account, but, I still see it under my Lambda trigger (it also says that this rule cannot be found any more because it is deleted - again, it still appears in my Lambda trigger and I want to CLEAN it using CLI.) I wish to DELETE the association (trigger) from my Lambda, not to delete the EventBridge TARGET which is the Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

The APIs you are looking for are in the EventBridge [events](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/events/index.html) client:

```
aws events list-rule-names-by-target --target-arn <lambda-arn>
aws events list-targets-by-rule --rule <rule-name-from-previous>
aws events remove-targets --rule <rule-name-from-previous> --ids <target-id-from-previous>
```

Note:  The terminology is a bit confusing.  An [Event Source Mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html) is the technical term for the particular polling-type Lambda integration pattern that handles the sources you mention.  It is not related to EventBridge events.

Comment: I believe you missed my point.
I have a working lambda function that has associated trigger with an Eventbridge rule which was already deleted in the past.
It is no longer exist in my account, but, I still see it under my lambda trigger (it also says that this rule cannot be found any more because it is deleted - again, it still appears in my lambda trigger and I want to CLEAN it using CLI.) I wish to DELETE the association (trigger) from my lambda, not to delete the eventbridge TARGET which is the lambda.

Comment: @Segev EventBridge Rules are displayed in the Lambda console as a UI convenience.  But \*EventBridge APIs\* manage the Rule-Lambda association.  For SQS, DynamoDB and the other Event Source Mapping integrations, Lambda APIs manage the association.  But for EventBridge Rules, the relevent actions are found in the EventBridge APIs in my answer.

Comment: The EventBridge [remove-targets](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/events/remove-targets.html) API _"Removes the specified targets from the specified rule. When the rule is triggered, those targets are no longer be invoked."_   In other words, it won't delete your Lambda, if that's what you are afraid of.

Comment: @Segev Please run `list-rule-names-by-target` and edit the question with the result.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
"Removes the specified targets from the specified rule. When the rule is triggered, those targets are no longer be invoked." - This is not what I intend to do. I can not name a rule (--rule XXX) name because it is no longer exist in my account, the rule was already deleted. BUT - yet I still see it in the Lambda console UI under triggers tab (it is still associated there) and I can't find a way to remove it using CLI command.
Again, I do not wish to delete the Eventbridge TARGET which is the lambda, because this rule is no longer exist!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `events` command:

```
aws events list-rule-names-by-target --target-arn <target_arn>
```

This will list the names of the rules that are associated with the specified *target_arn*. You can then use the `aws events describe-rule` command to get more information about each rule, including the rule id, schedule and pattern.

```
aws events describe-rule --name <rule_name>
```

Now to remove a trigger for a Lambda function in EventBridge:

```
aws events remove-targets --rule <rule_name> --ids <target_id>
```

The *target_id* is the unique identifier for the trigger that you want to remove, and the *rule_name* is the name of the rule that the trigger is associated with.

Comment: I believe you missed my point.
I have a working lambda function that has associated trigger with an Eventbridge rule which was already deleted in the past.
It is no longer exist in my account, but, I still see it under my lambda trigger (it also says that this rule cannot be found any more because it is deleted - again, it still appears in my lambda trigger and I want to CLEAN it using CLI.)